# How do I set a custom GNOME Shell theme permanently?

Tags: gnome, themes

Each time I do a computer restart the GNOME Shell theme I have enabled before the restart gets reset to the 'default' theme when I log in after a restart.  The default theme is the black panel.  Is it possible to set the theme to stick to my custom theme?

Comment: What method are you using to set the theme?

Answer (score 2):

I simply followed the instructions given on this site:

http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/10/how-to-install-and-manage-gnome-shell.html

Simply put:

1. Install `gnome-tweak-tool` (e.g., `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` in the Terminal)
2. Unzip a theme into the `~/.themes` directory, e.g. `~/.themes/Faience/`
3. Open `gnome-tweak-tool` (appears in the menu as "Advanced Settings")
4. Open the "Shell Extensions" section and set "User Themes Extension" to "ON"
5. Open the "Theme" section and select "Faience" (my theme) in the "Shell theme" dropdown list

I rebooted, and my theme remained the same.

Comment: That's how I set my theme.  I installed gnome shell from the software center.  Rebooted into GNOME, downloaded themes from this ppa:  http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/satyas-gnome-shell-gtk-themes-ppa.html, I installed gnome tweak tool, I also installed MSGE's.  When I reboot the theme gets reset to default, but when I open up the tweak tool, the theme is not default but the custom theme so I have to select a different theme and then set the custom theme again.

Comment: Did you install the User Themes extension from the official GNOME Extensions website? If so, remove it (should be under ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/) and only use the one in the WebUpd8 GNOME 3 PPA. Let me know if it works...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When I rebooted or do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `r` it would reset to the default shell theme. I have installed it with the webupd8 ppa.

I look with my nose :P. I had the extension two times; I disabled one and it works.